# Webcam permission getUserMedia in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcam

We are currently using a getUserMedia function to access web cam in a web application

Our getUserMedia function works when run locally on chrome, however, we get the following error when we run online through GitHub + DNS.

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this
>   feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure
>   origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Any ideas on how to run it on a webserver?

Initial thoughts to solve the problem
1. SSL 
2. More sophisticated function

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function (stream) {
    if (window.URL) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
        video.src = stream; // Opera.
    }
```

Comment: *"it breaks"* In what way, what happens? Is there a specific error message?

Comment: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no alternative to HTTPS to do this in JavaScript, and this is unlikely to change: more new potentially-sensitive features are being made HTTPS-only over time. If you're viewing the page through GitHub pages at a URL like `http://example.github.io`, you may be able to just switch `http` to `https` and be done with it. Otherwise, you'll need to figure out what options your server/hosting solution can provide (adding [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) might be the easiest option).